# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Email server's external IP address when the Azure VM starts

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, ip-address, task-scheduler

I have been trying to setup a task in the task scheduler that sends an email to me when the server starts. The email should contain the external IP address of the azure virtual machine.

What should be the trigger? I am using startup at the moment.
What should be the Action? If I use Send an Email then I dont know where to get the IP address from and how to include it in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure provides a friendly cloud DNS name so you'll never need to get it directly from the machine, it should be something like availiblitysetname.cloudapp.net pinging this should give you the IP

or if you really need the actual ip you can always use powershell to get the vIP

Get-AzureVM -Name "thevmname" -ServiceName "theservicename" | Get-AzureEndpoint | select { $_.Vip }